# Nodes of the ground state of a system of Schrödinger equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

In 1D, a single wave function that satisfies Schrödinger's equation representing the ground state for some $V(x)$ has no nodes.

Suppose now that you have a system of $N\neq 1$ coupled Schrödinger equations in one space dimension. Will the eigenvector associated to the ground state have no nodes? I understand that the ground state can then be degenerate, however.

Comment: How do you couple your $N$ Schrödinger's equations? What do you mean by coupling? Do you mean just a single Schrödinger's equation for an $N$-particle system?

Comment: @Ruslan I misunderstood him/her in the beginning, but now I also think that he envisages something like $N > 1$ oscillators in 1D.

Comment: Suppose that you have $N$ solutions, $f_1, f_2,...,f_n$, to a system of coupled Schrödinger equations, but an example of a potential I would eventually want to solve a Schrödinger equation for is $V(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x) + x^2$...

Comment: Schrödinger's equation is usually solved for wavefunction. Are your $f_i$ the wavefunctions? If yes, then your potential depending on wavefunctions looks strangely — this would be a system of nonlinear Schrödinger's equations. And it even makes little sense because the wavefunctions are in general complex.